# SSRS- Import multiple txt documents as data source

Tags: reporting-services, text-files, datasource

I have a txt file that is an output from a very odd system. There are no fields and the "columns" refer to spans represented by coordinates along the line of the file (so, 4 digit year would be phrased as character spaces "200-203"). I was writing a console app to handle this and reading a line and then doing .ToCharArray() was perfect.

Then I got direction that the report is to be written in SSRS and I'm totally out of clues on how do this. I've searched the web with several variations on keywords but no one really addresses my problem with the file being completely non-delimited and addressed by character space.

Bonus points if you can address the fact that I have to connect to 13 of these non-delimited files in the same SSRS report. Each file contributes one line of the final report, with counts of interest occupying the SSRS cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom DLL, that holds a class that manipulates the files the way you want it and return the final result to the tablix or a any control in the SSRS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/custom-assemblies/deploying-a-custom-assembly